# position relative and absolute doens't work properly

Tags: html, css, positioning

According to the official documentation, the

> **position absolute:**
>
> position an element to his first anchestor relatively positioned. So,
>   i want to realize five stars with a number inside them (at his
>   centre). Every star and number is placed into a container positioned
>   relatively, but i noted that the number are always positioned
>   absolutly respect to the FIRST container instead of his nearest
>   parent. In fact numbers overlpas each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/FMKMr/

**HTML**

```
<div id="vota">
      <div class="contStella" id="stellauno"><img class="stellaVota" src="http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/super-mono-reflection/yellow/star_yellow.png"/> <div class="numeroVota">1</div> </div>
      <div class="contStella" id="stelladue"><img class="stellaVota" src="http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/super-mono-reflection/yellow/star_yellow.png"/> <div class="numeroVota">2</div> </div>
      <div class="contStella" id="stellatre"><img class="stellaVota" src="http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/super-mono-reflection/yellow/star_yellow.png"/> <div class="numeroVota">3</div> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .contStella
    {
        position:relative;

    }

    .numeroVota
    {
       position:absolute;
        font-size:40px;
        margin-left:15px;
        color:blue;
    }

    .stellaVota
    {
        float:left;
        height:50px;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-block;` to the contStella class like this:

```
.contStella
{
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.numeroVota
{
   position:absolute;
    font-size:40px;
    margin-left:15px;
    color:blue;
}

.stellaVota
{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FMKMr/3/

Answer (score 3):

[**See this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FMKMr/11/)

When working with `position: absolute`, you should always set a horizontal and vertical value like `top` and `left`

```
.contStella
{
   position:relative;        
   float: left;
}

.numeroVota
{
   position:absolute;
   font-size:40px;
   margin-left:15px;
   color:blue;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.stellaVota
{
   height:50px;
}
```

You floated the wrong element. In ordner to get them in a row you need to float `.contStella`